# Preferable to extract fields before or after a JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6. I have two tables, `story` and `slide`: `slide` has a foreign key to `story`.

Is there any difference in performance terms between a standard JOIN query like this:

```
SELECT story.*, slide.name, slide.story_id 
FROM story 
JOIN slide ON story.id=slide.story_id 
WHERE slide.index=0;
```

And a subquery like this, which extracts the fields of interest first and only then joins them:

```
SELECT story.*, slide.name, slide.story_id 
FROM story 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM slide WHERE index=0) slide 
ON story.id=slide.story_id;
```

I've been looking at the output of `EXECUTION ANALYSE`, and it looks like both have exactly the same execution plan.

If there is no difference in performance terms, is one preferable to the other stylistically?

Comment: Version 1 is much better - stylistically!!!

Comment: I dont' think there is performance difference. I prefer first version.  I just suggest to avoid using SELECT *.  Instead use a list of columns name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is preferably stylistically . . just in case.  I would write it using table aliases:

```
SELECT st.*, sl.name,
       sl.story_id   -- unnecessary
FROM story st JOIN
     slide sl
     ON st.id = sl.story_id 
WHERE sl.index = 0;
```

And, why are you selecting `sl.story_id`?  It just repeats `st.id`.

The "just in case" is because some databases materialize subqueries (not Postgres, at least not all the time) -- and that adds additional overhead.  In addition, the subquery really adds nothing to making the logic more understandable.  I'm a big fan of subqueries, but not of using them unnecessarily.